# How do I access the nested fields in the dataframe .proto, ScalaPB

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, protocol-buffers, spark-streaming, scalapb

The following my dataframe schema

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- addresses: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to output name and city. The following is my spark streaming app which outputs name and addresses, but I want name and cities in the output.
Appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
object PersonConsumer {
  import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, SparkSession}
  import com.example.protos.demo._

  def main(args : Array[String]) {

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.
      master("local")
      .appName("spark session example")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").
      option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092").
      option("subscribe","person").load()

    val ds2 = ds1.map(row=> row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value")).map(Person.parseFrom(_)).select($"name", $"addresses")

    ds2.printSchema()

    val query = ds2.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple get the dataframe of name and city and then you can use it, for getting dataframe of name and city you can select both as follows

```
ds1.select("name","addresses.element.city")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sandeep. select("name","addresses.element.city") gives me error because adresses is a Seq[Address] and I want all the cities in the output.

Finally I wrote the following function to get all the cities..

```
    def getCities(addresses: Seq[Address]) : String = {
      var cities:String = ""
      if (addresses.size > 0) {
        cities = (for(a <- addresses) yield a.city.getOrElse("")).mkString(",")
//        cities = addresses.foldLeft("")((str,addr) => str  + addr.city.getOrElse(""))
      }
      cities
    }
```